# Should I prefer variables or multiple indirections on arrays in C# in perf critical code?

Tags: c#, performance

in some perf critical program (single threaded), if I have arrays of primitive types, and need to access the same index of those more than once in loops.

Should I use tmp variables, or would just constant indirection on the array be better/faster ?

I could imagine also that it is possible that either is the same / is transparently optimised at compile time.

Comment: That's true to some extent but it also depends on how and where you declare these arrays in regards to optimization do you have a code snippet of what you are wanting to try..?

Comment: Array access has constant time: `O(1)`.

Comment: Yes, but in terms of complexity, variables access also is O(1), this has more to do with low level software

Comment: @vulkanino it's also O(1) for me to walk to California for fresh asparagus.  That doesn't mean it's faster than walking to my refrigerator, or eating the one I've already got on my plate.

Comment: @vulkanino big o notation is a measure of how an operation will scale with input, it does little to say how fast in execution time a given operation will be.

Comment: @chris,@Jared yes, I just wanted to point out that the access speed with an array, being constant, does not depend on the size of the array. In other words: he shouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *general* access to an array is slower than a temporary because it has 2 additional pieces of overhead

- A layer of indirection
- A bounds check

However I would **not** be changing any code I had today based on that knowledge unless a profiler clearly showed a tight loop to be a significant perf problem in my application.  And furthermore showed that changing to a cached local produced a significant perf benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Lets test this:

```
  int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  int t = arr[3];
  int a = 0;
  var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
  {
    a += t;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(a);
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow-start);
  a = 0;
  start = DateTime.UtcNow;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
  {
    a += arr[3];
  }
  Console.WriteLine(a);
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow - start);
```

Output:

```
-294967296
00:00:02.1925000
-294967296
00:00:03.4250000
```

Yes its slower to access the array repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, and +1 for actually going to the effort to write the test, but look at what you've shown- you get a .5s difference for a *billion* accesses. A simple GC cycle could easily introduce that level of difference, thus Jared and I mentioning avoiding micro-optimization.

Comment: I totally agree on micro optimization. You don't even get twice the performance by not using the array. I think it will depend on what he does and how time critical it is. Garbage collection can mixup any timing and thats way worse in a realtime application.

Answer (score 2):

Array access always involves indirection, so if there are frequent accesses the variable will likely be faster.

That said, I find it incredibly unlikely that you will be able to measure the difference.  This is an example of micro-optimization.